# Android sqlite query where with string

Tags: android, sqlite

Why do I get an error with this code?

```
public Cursor getAllTitlesFromInnerListGroup(String tablename, String grp) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID_T, KEY_NAME_T, KEY_PRIORITY_T, KEY_FINISHED_T, KEY_NOTES_T, KEY_HIDDEN_T, KEY_QUANTITY_T, KEY_GROUP_T};
    //return ourDatabase.query("GL_" + tablename, columns, KEY_GROUP_T + "='Volvo'", null, null, null, null); //this works
    return ourDatabase.query("GL_" + tablename, columns, KEY_GROUP_T + "=" + grp, null, null, null, null);
}
```

> 04-18 21:10:53.118: E/AndroidRuntime(30721): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Volvo: ,
>   while compiling: SELECT _id, grlist_name, grlist_priority,
>   grlist_finished, grlist_notes, grlist_hidden, grlist_quantity,
>   grlist_group FROM GL_table WHERE grlist_group=Volvo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
return ourDatabase.query("GL_" + tablename, columns, KEY_GROUP_T + "=" + grp,
null, null, null, null);
```

To this:

```
return ourDatabase.query("GL_" + tablename, columns, KEY_GROUP_T + "= ?" ,
new String[]{grp}, null, null, null);
```